# Curl displays incomprehensible characters instead of an answer

Tags: curl

[image]

I want to print: `Message received`
But for the place of this, symbols are incomprehensible.

My cURL request:
`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"time\": \"2019-12-27T09:50:02.000+0000\", \"unread\": true, \"message\": \"asd\", \"from\": \"Vadim\"}" localhost:8080/api/save`

Code

```
  @Override
    public ResponseEntity<String> add(@RequestBody  Message message) {
        try {
            message.setTime(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
            repository.save(message);
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Message Received", HttpStatus.OK);

        }catch (Exception e) {
         return new ResponseEntity<>(e.toString(), HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i add code now )

Comment: Probably problem with russian language decoding. Try to change decoding

Comment: i change code translate to english

Comment: and what happened? same error?

Comment: How can I change the encoding

Comment: You should use not cmd but something like Postman for sending your messages